# Creating Cron Jobs in C#

Tags: windows, sqlite, c#-4.0, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a Scheduling type application in C#, and allowing the user to store tasks that they want to run at certain times. Right now I give them the option of specifying how often to run it (Daily/Weekly/Monthly) as well as specify a time, which is then stored in a Database.

I am having a little bit of trouble just wrapping my head around the pseudo code behind this, and am looking for some suggestions about how to implement it. I am running a repeating timer every 60 seconds to check each task to see if it needs to run, but always seem to hit road blocks when I need to work with Date/Time and adding Recurring Day (daily/weekly/etc) has complicated it even more.

Comment: Check out Quartz.NET. It is a free task scheduling app. There is a fair chance you don't need to write your own solution. http://quartznet.sourceforge.net