# how to run code depending on the time

Tags: c#, asmx

I have a little problem. I didn't find a suitable title, sorry

I have a time column at my database and I want to do something (not important) whenever `currenttime==timeValueAtMyDatabase`. How?

```
if(currenttime==timeValueAtMyDatabase)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: What kind of application ? ASP.Net, WinForm, WPF ? can't you use operating system scheduler ?

Comment: Use the Windows scheduler or Quartz.NET.

Comment: Asmx. I'm trying to push notification

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can't do push notifications in ASMX.

Comment: Aside: ASMX is beyond deprecated. WCF or Web API are probably better choices.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Couldn't you schedule a push notification in a long-running app in reaction to an ASMX request. Or did you mean that the execution model of ASMX precludes any long-running tasks?

Comment: Thanks, i think i'm not going to use ASMX again. I first think best aproach is creating a new .cs file which runs backgroung, read from database and push notification. There is nothing ASMX have to do.

Comment: @millimoose: the execution model of ASMX (or ASP.NET in general) makes long-running requests a very bad idea. It's simple request/response. And there is no ability to do anything other than just respond. It's an ancient piece of code, little-changed since .NET 1.0 back in 2001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with the code executing in a different thread and you can use whatever libraries you want (Rx in this case), I personally prefer this method:

```
Observable.Timer(timeToDoTheThing).Subscribe(codeToRun);
```

`timeToDoTheThing` is the time that the code should be executed at and `codeToRun` is the code that will run when the time is reached (in the form of a void returning delegate that takes one long parameter).

Some things to note:

1. The event will occur immediately if the time provided is in the past.
2. The event will execute in a background thread.  You can control which thread it runs in by providing a scheduler, but that is a bit more complex and I prefer to just make my code thread safe rather than trying to control which threads execute which blocks of code.

Below is a complete program that will exemplify this.  You will need to install the Rx-Main NuGet package to the project for it to work and build against .NET 4+.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    public class Class
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var timeToDoTheThing = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 10, 19, 22, 19, 30, TimeSpan.Zero);
            Action<long> codeToRun = _ => Console.WriteLine("It is time.");
            Observable.Timer(timeToDoTheThing).Subscribe(codeToRun);

            Thread.Sleep(100000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what i'm loking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows Forms Application, you can use a timer and check whether some of the entries are less then `DateTime.Now`.

If it is a web application, you can use a cron job. Check out the following link: [Creating Cron Jobs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815608/creating-cron-jobs-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer control that ticks on appropriate intervals.
On ever tick compare the current time with the time in your database.
You will need to account for differences. For example if it ticks at 0.1sec, 1.1sec, 2.1sec and the time in your database is 1sec. 
You'll have to find an appropriate way to account for such differences.